# Erlang ei ei_decode_version and other functions undefined reference

Tags: c, erlang

I try to use C code in erlang with ei library.

I try to build my code with:

```
-I/usr/local/lib/erlang/erts-5.8.5/include/ -I/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/erl_interface-3.7.5/include -O2 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0
```

But i got error that ei functions undefined reference.

My simple code:

```
int main(void) {
    ei_x_buff result;
    ei_x_encode_atom(&result, "ok");
    return 0;
}

 undefined reference to `ei_x_encode_atom'
```

How can i fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

undefined reference is linker error. It means you need to link your code with erl_interface library.

practically you need to use -L option to point where is erl_interface library and -l option to specify library to link.

Kind of

```
ld -L/usr/local/otp/lib/erl_interface-3.2.3/lib \
            myprog.o -lerl_interface -lei -o myprog
```

(It's example from documentation)